# SAX ParseException Error

Tags: php, soap, xmlhttprequest

I am calling a web service in PHP SOAP by sending XML Request but i don't know what's happening i am getting following error.Though i have gone through the web but didn't got any answer.Kindly help any one.
The error is as follows :

```
soapenv:Server.userExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "hb:getHotelValuedAvail" is not bound.
```

The code that  am using is as follows:-

```
$user = "Username";
$pass = "Password";
$destino = "Test.wsdl";
$objClient = new SoapClient($destino, array('trace' => true,'exceptions' => 0, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'));
$xml = '<hb:getHotelValuedAvail xmlns:hb="http://axis.frontend.hydra.hotelbeds.com" xsi:type="xsd:string"><HotelValuedAvailRQ echoToken="DummyEchoToken" sessionId="DummySessionId" xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRQ.xsd"><Language>ENG</Language><Credentials><User>'.$user.'</User><Password>'.$pass.'</Password></Credentials><PaginationData pageNumber="1" itemsPerPage="999"/><CheckInDate date="20121013"/><CheckOutDate date="20121015"/><Destination code="PMI" type="SIMPLE"/><OccupancyList><HotelOccupancy>          <RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy></OccupancyList></HotelValuedAvailRQ></hb:getHotelValuedAvail>';

$soapvar = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);
$objResponse = $objClient->__soapCall("getHotelValuedAvail", array($soapvar)); 
print_r($objClient->__getLastResponse());
```

I have wasted many days on this. Even asked with the support but no help found.

Comment: What sort of documentation have you looked at to learn about the problem? Where did it fall short? What have you already done to try fixing the problem?

Comment: Hey Ben, i have looked into the HotelBed Doc provided by my client though i am using the same format still i don't understand why it is not working.